# Sending data from FormView to my database using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, formview

I have multiple FormViews within my ASP.NET application which have different controls within them such as text box's and drop down lists.

Firstly in my database I have a list of users with lots of details. In my application I have a text box where I can search for a user and it will populate one of my form views using the SqlDataSource, however my other form views do not get automatically populated when searched and this is the section that the user will fill in and press submit to then submit all of the data including the pre populated data back to the database.

I am not sure where to start for this and would appreciate it if someone can either give me some examples or point me in the correct direction as to how to do this.

Here is an example of one of my FormViews:

```
            <div class="compliant-details">
            <asp:FormView runat="server" DataSourceID="ds_complaints" CssClass="complient-details-first-section" DefaultMode="Insert">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <div class="compliant-details-method">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Method:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_method" DataSourceID="ds_compliantmethod"
                            DataTextField="ComplaintMethod" DataValueField="ComplaintMethodId" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="<Please Select>" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-type">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Type:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox ddl" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_type" DataSourceID="ds_types"
                            DataTextField="TypeName" DataValueField="TypeId" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-status">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Status:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_status" DataSourceID="ds_status"
                            DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="StatusId" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="<Please Select>" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-catagory">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Catagory:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_catagory" DataSourceID="ds_category"
                            DataTextField="Category" DataValueField="Categoryid" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="<Please Select>" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-recorded-by">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Recorded By:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_recorded_by" DataSourceID="ds_agents"
                            DataTextField="AgentName" DataValueField="AgentId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-handeld-by">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Handeld By:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList class="smallinputbox" runat="server" ID="ddl_compliant_details_handald_by" readonly="readonly" DataSourceID="ds_agents"
                            DataTextField="AgentName" DataValueField="AgentId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-rfc-sent">
                        <label class="applicationfont">RFC Sent:</label>
                        <div class="compliant-details-rfc-rb">
                            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb_compliant_details_rfc_sent_yes" Text="Yes" CssClass="applicationfont" GroupName="rfcsent" />
                            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb_compliant_details_rfc_sent_no" Text="No" CssClass="applicationfont" GroupName="rfcsent" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="compliant-details-accepted-by-client">
                        <label class="applicationfont">Accepted By Client:</label>
                        <div class="compliant-details-accepted-rb">
                            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb_compliant_details_accepted_by_client_yes" Text="Yes" CssClass="applicationfont" />
                            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb_compliant_details_accepted_by_client_no" Text="No" CssClass="applicationfont" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the "Edit Template" on the same FormView?

- User searches.
- FormView populates.
- User can press "Edit" which will change the form mode to Edit.
- User presses "SUBMIT" and then the changes are sent to the database.

Why have more than one FormView?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I have merged them all into one FormView now but am struggling to understand how I use the Edit Template, do you know any examples?

Comment: Can you repost your HTML with the EDIT TEMPLATE information?  Best thing you can do is to create a new form view, based on your SQL data source, to try this out.   Create the SQL Data source.  Configure it. When you are selecting your TABLE, pick your fields, making sure to include your Primary Key.  Hit ADVANCED. Generate Insert/Update/Delete...  Then place a new formview, using the SQL Data Source as the data source.  Then look at the resulting HTML that shows up.  You will see EDIT/INSERT/ITEM templates.  These are fully customizable, so you can do what you want.  This is just the default.

Comment: Item template will have labels for everything, as they are not editable.  Insert will have text boxes for everything, as you can enter data.  Edit will be like the Insert, but will pre-populate the data to edit.  Customizing: Add combo boxes, or change TextBox to Labels, for instance, if you don't want particular fields to be editable.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I found out how to do this with help from you by using only one form view and connecting the data behind within the C# code.